# Change variable in document.ready JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What is wrong with my script? It doesn't change variable `d` after on click function. I tried also `window.d` but still the same.

```
var d = undefined;
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 460) {
         d = $(window).scrollTop();
    } else {
        d = 459;
    }

    if (d < 459) {

        $('#drop1, #drop2, #drop3').on('click',function(){

            $.scrollTo(460, 900, { easing: 'easeOutExpo' });
            $(document).scroll();
            d = 500;
        });    

    } else {
        console.log(window.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you *please* use [reasonable indentation](http://jsbeautifier.org/)?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't change it? You don't seem to be testing for the value anywhere after a click occurred. I think you may have a misunderstanding of how events, or event driven code in general, works.

Comment: onclick function should work only when d is smaller than 459. And If I set that d is 500 in function it seems that id doesn't work. I also see it in console.log

Comment: `scrollTop() !== 460` sets `d = 459` in every case except in the rare case where scrollTop() yields *exactly* 460px. However, afterwards you check for `(d < 459)` - this means in most of the cases you will actually never run the if branch containing your click handler. So in most cases this handler get's never registered. I suppose either `$(window).scrollTop() !== 460` is wrong and you meant either `<=` or `>=` or you should write `if (d <= 459)`. In any case, having an eventhandler capsulated in a condition looks like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @parat10 You could try writing what you want to do in pseudo code and then translate it into javascript

Comment: *"I also see it in console.log"* I only see one `console.log` statement here, and that is executed only if the event handler is not even added to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment "onclick function should work only when d is smaller than 459", I wonder if this is what he's looking for:

```
var d = undefined;
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 460) {
         d = $(window).scrollTop();
    } else {
        d = 459;
    }

    $('#drop1, #drop2, #drop3').on('click',function() {
       // move d<459 test inside click event
       // the click event will always be fired, but the 
       // scroll effect will only occur if d<459
       if (d < 459) {
            $.scrollTo(460, 900, { easing: 'easeOutExpo' });
            $(document).scroll();
            d = 500;
        };  
        console.log(d);  // always tell me d for debugging
    }};
});
```

Of course, the click event may only trigger the scroll effect once; it then sets d=500 and, unless d is being reset again somewhere else, `(d < 459)` will never be true again.